# Java proxies connection to postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, proxy

Could someone help me or suggest a solution? I want to connect from a computer that has firewall to other where the postgres server run. The problem is that computer (client) has a firewall and I don't have access to configure it, or open ports, ping does not respond. The computer (server) where PostgreSQL has open ports but I cannot connect to it from another because of a firewall. I can only access the computer through proxy.

How I could with Java programming access remotely through proxy to postgres forgetting firewall?

Java has a connection with proxies. But I don't know how to put it together with postgres connection.

```
        System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
        System.getProperties().put( "proxyHost", "67.210.82.198" );
        System.getProperties().put( "proxyPort", "80" );

        URL validateURL = new URL("http://domain.com");
        URLConnection urlConnection = validateURL.openConnection();

        //how put together ???

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://ipPublica:5432/DataBase","user", "pass");
```

Comment: "proxySet" does nothing. Proof: set it to "false". There is not and has never been such a property in the JDK, various books and online references notwithstanding. It came from the long-defunct HotJavaBean, an encapsulated browser, died a death in about 1998.

Answer (score 6):

That can't be done. PostgreSQL connections are not HTTP connections. Yo cannot use an HTTP proxy for PostgreSQL. Maybe a socks proxy will do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "67.210.82.198");
System.setPropery("http.proxyPort", "80");

String url = "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user","myUsername");
props.setProperty("password","myPassword");
props.setProperty("ssl","true");

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

For more, see [java networking & proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

Comment: Thank you very much friend on monday will test with firewall, now i test locally (postgres server) and it work ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old. It also has been asked on the PostgreSQL mailing list:

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2010-08/msg00021.php

The answers over there boils down to:

- Use SOCKs
- **If** (big IF!) you want to hack the JDBC driver source, you **might** (big "might"!) be able to make it work over a HTTP-Proxy using SSL.
- Sidekick: Someone proposed an ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a SOCKS proxy, rather than a HTTP proxy.

Then your code will look something like this:

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", host);
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "1080");
```

Details:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html